# Pandas DatetimeIndex: Number of periods in a frequency string?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, datetimeindex

How can I get a count of the number of periods in a Pandas DatetimeIndex using a frequency string (offset alias)? For example, let's say I have the following DatetimeIndex:

```
idx = pd.date_range("2019-03-01", periods=10000, freq='5T')
```

I would like to know how many 5 minute periods are in a week, or '7D'. I can calculate this "manually":

```
periods = (7*24*60)//5
```

Or I can get the length of a dummy index:

```
len(pd.timedelta_range(start='1 day', end='8 days', freq='5T'))
```

Neither approach seems very efficient. Is there a better way using Pandas date functionality?

Comment: I edit my answer, see if is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out a reasonable solution:

```
pd.to_timedelta('7D')//idx.freq
```

This has the advantage that I can specify a range using a frequency string (offset alias) and the period or frequency is inferred from the dataframe. The numpy solution suggested by @Terry is still the fastest solution where speed is important.

Answer (score 1):

try using `numpy`

```
len(np.arange(pd.Timedelta('1 days'), pd.Timedelta('8 days'), timedelta(minutes=5)))

out:
2016
```

My testing, first import `time`:

```
import time
```

the OP solution:

```
start_time = time.time()
len(pd.timedelta_range(start='1 day', end='8 days', freq='5T'))
print((time.time() - start_time))

out:
0.0011057853698730469]
```

using `numpy`

```
start_time = time.time()
len(np.arange(pd.Timedelta('1 day'), pd.Timedelta('8 days'), timedelta(minutes=5)))
print((time.time() - start_time))

out:
0.0001723766326904297
```

---

Follow the sugestion of @meW, doing the performance test using timeit

using `timedelta_range`:

```
%timeit len(pd.timedelta_range(start='1 day', end='8 days', freq='5T'))
out:
91.1 µs ± 1.31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

using numpy:

```
%timeit len(np.arange(pd.Timedelta('1 day'), pd.Timedelta('8 days'), timedelta(minutes=5)))
out:
16.3 µs ± 196 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: Terry, the question is about efficiency not the alternatives. May be your solution is right. So, to make it a solid answer try comparing your solution with other alternatives and provide the insights. Hope you get my point!

Comment: @neW But in the scope of OP, `numpy` is much more fast

Comment: That's what I just said, if you can prove it with some dummy data that would make it a good answer else no worries!

Comment: For better optimization results, use `%timeit` for one liner or `%%timeit` for multiple lines ;)

Comment: Interesting answers, but shouldn't it be possible to calculate a solution directly rather than generate a dummy index with the sole purpose of determining the length?

Comment: @Turanga1 probably yes but I do not know how =/

Comment: @meW i appreciate the suggestion, i hope I did it right