# Pandas Approximate Frequency Per Year of a DateTimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, frequency, datetimeindex

I have a multiple Timeseries in different files and I know that Pandas can infer the frequency of the DateTimeIndex for each:

```
pd.infer_freq(data.index)
```

Is there a programmatic way to get the approximate frequency per year from general files.  For instance:

```
'M' -> 12
'BM' -> 12
'B' -> 252
'D' -> 365
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54945550/pandas-datetimeindex-number-of-periods-in-a-frequency-string is close but I'm not sure how to adapt the answer.

Comment: Though this is a cool question, given that there are a very small number of common frequencies, practically it might just be easier to calculate them yourself and store them in a dict in some script. The solution I proposed is a bit overkill, and perhaps doesn't always give you the number you want, but if you want to include a `calendar` with `pd.bdate_range` to exclude holidays , you should be able to modify it to get the number

Answer (score 1):

Here's one alternative. We'll create a date_range using the provided frequency and then groupby to figure out the most common number that fit into a year. The `periods` argument should be large enough such that given the frequency the date range creates many years of data. Really shouldn't need to change it, unless you want `ns` or something insanely small. (But for those it will be more efficient to just calculate manually).

```
def infer_periods_in_year(freq, periods=10**4):
    """
    freq : str pandas frequency alias.
    periods : numeric, given freq, should create many years. 
    """
    
    while True:
        try:
            s = pd.Series(data=pd.date_range('1970-01-01', freq=freq, periods=periods))
            break
        # If periods is too large
        except (pd.errors.OutOfBoundsDatetime, OverflowError, ValueError): 
            periods = periods/10
    
    return s.groupby(s.dt.year).size().value_counts().index[0]
```

---

```
infer_periods_in_year('D')
#365
infer_periods_in_year('BM')
#12
infer_periods_in_year('M')
#12
infer_periods_in_year('B')
#261
infer_periods_in_year('W')
#52
infer_periods_in_year('min', periods=10**7)
#525600
```